# Is it safe to have a frontend button that links directly to backend?

Tags: reactjs, rest, http, fastapi

I am creating a full stack application with a React/TS frontend and FastAPI Python backend both on different domains/origins. For my first API endpoint (an auth endpoint), I cannot use axios.get(/login) as I planned as I'm using a 3rd party API in my backend that doesn't work with redirects to my frontend. The solution seems to be to have a login button with an a tag that directly links to http://backend_url/login. This does work, but it feels weird/unsafe to literally send users on the frontend to the literal url of my backend as opposed to just calling HTTP requests to the backend. Is this bad practice? Is there a better way to accomplish this? I appreciate any direction.

Comment: This is not necessarily bad practice, but I don't understand exactly what is stopping you from just using your backend as, well, a backend? With 3rd party API, do you mean you are using a third party identity provider? If so, which one?

Comment: @JarroVGIT I mean I have my backend REST API my frontend communicates with, right. But, in my backend I'm using a 3rd party public API (Spotify in this case). The frontend is strictly the view, and the backend does all the Spotify API calls.

Comment: So your users need to authorize your app with Spotify, is that what you mean? So, user is forwarded to Spotify.com/authorize and is then redirected back to your app? (Basically, is what you are trying to solve oauth related?)

Comment: @JarroVGIT essentially yes. I've done some research and it seems for just the /authorize endpoint, Spotify needs it to be a direct redirect from client -> /authorize. This is a bit disappointing as I was hoping to be able to keep all my API calls strictly on the backend.

Answer (score 1):

The question is more on how to deal with a 3rd party API that a user needs to authorize, see comments on OP.

You can redirect directly from your frontend to the `/authorize` endpoint of Spotify. They will call the returnUrl that you gave when you registered your application with them, and provide a `authorization code`. If this is in your frontend (e.g. `http://frontend.com/oauth/callback`, that can take that authorization code and feeds it to your backend (for example, to `http://backend/api/auth`). That endpoint can exchange the authorization code for access tokens (calling the `/token` endpoint of Spotify, of something similar) using the client credentials that you received when you registered your application with Spotify. The backend can store and use those access tokens, and your frontend can call the backend.